# Is it possible to receive GCM messages in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-cloud-messaging

Using Java one would implement a BroadcastReceiver to use the "Google Cloud Messaging API for Android" and receive GCM multicast messages.

Can the same be achieved with Python (on a PC)? How?

Alternatively is is possible to get the messages on a PC running Ubuntu? (without using Chrome / the PC is a client / server is GAE)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is for GCM implementations. If you are planning a server-and-client setup where the PC is the server (the clients will always be Android devices), you can still receive GCM messages. Instead of downstream messaging (server to client app), it would be upstream (client app to server). To do this, you would need to implement an [XMPP setup](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html). There is a Python sample at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough. The PC is a client.